# Data.frame and different specifications linear regression models

Tags: r, dataframe, regression, linear-regression

This is my data.frame:

```
data <- matrix(rnorm(50*5),nrow=50)
m <- data.frame(data )
m

            X1          X2           X3           X4
1  -0.47903358  1.92799699 -0.584364168 -1.475276350
2   0.05464517  1.90064618  1.721449935  1.215188405
3   2.23782855  0.16839367 -0.074212064 -0.719745849
4   0.44476924  0.37247676  0.300423948  1.722222410
5  -0.66889333  0.26094142 -0.001254037  0.617630295
6  -1.17663634 -1.93020031 -2.813433555  0.350943310
7   2.16609882 -0.06594556  0.133278642  1.693078802
8  -0.16090564 -1.14454452 -1.340407149  0.574943347
9   0.46691283  0.98394614 -0.277273498  0.030499576
10  1.19049154  1.03160103  0.626364442  0.429348535
11  0.72593476  0.89130574 -0.599052058  2.012316875
12 -0.04748923 -1.38044706  0.058364936  0.825752213
13 -0.90407306  0.14790680  0.002608154 -0.991979288
14 -1.50113350  0.78807179 -2.371160466  0.559174890
15  0.04075635 -1.14486991  1.585769771 -0.495937216
16  1.29724449  0.47729721 -0.871033202  1.524746619
17  1.12384656 -0.07589516 -0.463837527  0.206108262
18  0.65092671  0.29660588 -1.096981115 -0.326524160
19 -0.54953490 -0.06792527 -0.543922865  0.211205138
20  0.19187346 -0.65190412 -1.674653668  0.712704645
21  0.97108788  0.91087005  0.182424518 -0.296413534
22  1.64975949  0.22140448 -0.075355571 -0.472299544
23  1.45613296 -1.29101443  1.231839302  0.774475499
24 -0.15324579 -1.31596417 -0.343467527  0.087122108
25  0.20305822 -0.96867715 -0.311745324 -1.483964874
26 -2.22916775  1.46982603 -0.254705650 -0.003573105
27  0.26135095 -0.44053524  0.208284330  0.459095264
28  0.55020951 -0.37742141  0.346186077  0.825811292
29 -0.78695097 -0.21014858  0.003055816  2.142121347
30 -0.33506969  0.31572240 -0.139970552  1.344697176
31 -0.94164226 -0.88366990 -0.906886069  0.774590884
32  3.23764133 -0.47556802  0.166917302  0.959307700
33 -0.64114926  0.16089400  1.942563410  0.142073261
34  0.03848502 -0.83066179  0.934403254  1.730448144
35 -0.34621698  0.65682342  1.601365990  0.160012282
36  0.62848314  0.33126945  0.188823549  2.380319403
37  1.02807329  1.07299920  0.398083643 -0.208241920
38 -0.50616984  1.68998408  0.427342040 -0.345264684
39  1.31721397 -1.17111247  1.754036030  0.755414080
40  1.23714888 -0.12253370  0.887065669  0.001770354
41  0.59541135  0.66438057  0.880643498  1.441513269
42  0.41100680  0.52757460  1.219644246  1.450262235
43  0.08984815  1.44830794  0.113193523 -0.620546777
44 -1.51411951 -0.17346499 -0.698924584 -0.767921061
45 -1.03652530  1.27296507  1.740954529 -0.467568299
46  1.14533381 -0.67304957 -0.384012335  0.637582075
47  0.37996214  0.53566774 -1.413930797  1.222728459
48 -0.53705734  0.77591264  0.375236588 -1.430924067
49  0.64051195 -0.22562951 -1.667050192  0.345009059
50 -1.19521122  1.18436746 -0.905004199 -0.005221906
```

Well, I want now estimate 3 different models.

```
X1 = X2 + X3 + X4
X1 = X2^2 + X3(Lag1) + X4^2
ln(X1)=X2^2 + X3(Lag1) + X4^2
```

As im a begginer in R im not able to implement a function to do this. 
I'm reading the lm function and still can not implement these models. The way I could implement was very rudimentary, ie, I was riding a data.frame for each model.

Thanks

Comment: To use `lm()` you would need a formula to regress on. Your outcome data has to be a column in your data frame. The "t" value in your formula should be a constant in your data frame to be used. Once you have that you can create a string your formula and regress on that.

So, Y needs to be in your data.frame and t needs to be in your as data.frame as well as your x values. An example formula would be the string: `Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3`. The `~` icon you can think of as an equals sign.

Comment: Thanks for answer  giraffehere. I edited the question.

Comment: You'd also need column for a lagged variable of X3, but I'll write out an answer on how to do this. Just note that you need a column for every variable in the regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use lm() you need at least two things. You need a formula and you need data to apply that formula to. In your case, here's how you would code to run a very simple, basic, linear regression on your data. Again, you need an "X3_Lag1" variable (literally a column called that which has the lag applied) in your data to regress on lagged data (make a new column with X3 pushed down a row) and then cut the data for that missing value in row one.

```
# Getting the first model.
formula1 <- "X1 ~ X2 + X3 + X4"
lin1 <- lm(formula1, data)
summary(lin1) # This will give you the coefficients for each value.

# Getting the second model.
formula2 <- "X1 ~ X2^2 + X3_Lag1 + X4^2"
lin2 <- lm(formula2, data)
summary(lin2)

# Getting the third model.
formula3 <- "log(X1) ~ X2^2 + X3_Lag1 + X4^2"
lin3 <- lm(formula3, data)
summary(lin3)
```

WARNING: I believe you will get an error on the third formula because you're taking the natural log of a negative number, which is not possible. Please take care of that being the case.

Comment: i was thinking about how i can do it without include columns. I did this `lm(X1 ~ X2 + I(X3^2), m)`. I dont need to include the x3^2 column. And `lm(log(X1) ~ X2 + I(X3^2) , m)`. The lagged variable is the problem.

Comment: You don't need an "X3^2" column for that operator, that will work, giving you the square of each number in the X3 column. For the lagged variable, however, to my knowledge you will need an "X3_Lag1" column, which you'll need to make in your data. To my knowledge, there is no method for creating a lag in the formula itself, you must do it outside of the formula and in the data beforehand.

My concern with log(X1) is that you have negative values in your X1 column, which are not allowed in logarithms.